# dynDNS in android

Tags: android, dyndns

I have an android application to develop. And I must connect to a database and get data. I use servlet. My problem is about dynamic ip. How can I fix that ? Do u know DynDNS? 
Thanks!

Comment: Who's dynamic ip? Do you mean you server doesn't have static ip addr?

Comment: I mean server of my customer have a dynamic ip. The corporation where i am working has a static ip.

Answer (score 2):

Create an account on dyndns.org and register for a domain name, and register your current IP address.  In your app do the following periodically :

- check your current ip  : `http://checkip.dyndns.com/` can be used to check your IP http://dyn.com/support/developers/checkip-tool/
- update your ip to dyndns.org by the following method:

  `http://username:password@members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=yourhostname&myip=ipaddress&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG`

Replace `username` and `password` with your account password and username,
           `yourhostname` would be the name you registered on dyndns.org  and `ipaddress` is the current IP address.

and you are done .. for details http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/perform-update/